# Why is `MLFLOW_RUN_ID` being deleted after being fetched from environment variables?

Tags: python, mlflow

In the `start_run` method that is available in the module `/tracking/fluent.py` , there is a section where it checks for environment variable `MLFLOW_RUN_ID`, and if it's available, resumes with that run_id . But right after if finds the environment variable, it is being deleted. Why is that?

Doesn't this restrict the availability of resume run option to just once?
What if I'd like to resume a run multiple times in a module?

```
...
...

elif _RUN_ID_ENV_VAR in os.environ:
    existing_run_id = os.environ[_RUN_ID_ENV_VAR]
    del os.environ[_RUN_ID_ENV_VAR]
...
...
```

Comment: I suspect it's to prevent an infinite loop.

Comment: What infinite loop?

Comment: I don't know what miflow is, but it seems like this is intended to prevent it from restarting again.